# How to .apply() a layer to the outputs of a model (transfer learning)

Tags: javascript, tensorflow.js, tfjs-node

I am trying to finetune a CNN in tensorflow.js. To do this, I would like to add a head to the final layer of the pretrained model. The equivalent code in python tensorflow is as follows, where we add an average pooling layer to the pretrained efficientnet.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

img_base = tf.keras.applications.efficientnet.EfficientNetB0(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')
img_base = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(img_base.output)
```

However, the same code in JavaScript results in an error.

```js
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');

const getModel = async function () {
    const imgBase = await tf.loadLayersModel('file://./tfjs_models/efficientnetb0_applications_notop/model.json');
    const imgPoolLayer = tf.layers.globalAveragePooling2d({dataFormat: 'channelsLast'});
    const imgPool = imgPoolLayer.apply(imgBase.outputs);
}
```

```
Error: Arguments to apply() must be all SymbolicTensors or all Tensors
    at new ValueError (/home/stanleyzheng/kds/kds-melanoma/tfjs_scripts/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-layers/dist/tf-layers.node.js:16792:28)
    at Concatenate.Layer.apply (/home/stanleyzheng/kds/kds-melanoma/tfjs_scripts/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-layers/dist/tf-layers.node.js:19983:19)
    at getModel (/home/stanleyzheng/kds/kds-melanoma/tfjs_scripts/train.js:32:29)
```

Printing `imgBase.outputs` gives us the following result. `imgBase.outputs[0]` returns the same error as above.

```js
[
  SymbolicTensor {
    dtype: 'float32',
    shape: [ null, 1280, 7, 7 ],
    sourceLayer: Activation {
      _callHook: null,
      _addedWeightNames: [],
      _stateful: false,
      id: 236,
      activityRegularizer: null,
      inputSpec: null,
      supportsMasking: true,
      _trainableWeights: [],
      _nonTrainableWeights: [],
      _losses: [],
      _updates: [],
      _built: true,
      inboundNodes: [Array],
      outboundNodes: [],
      name: 'top_activation',
      trainable_: true,
      initialWeights: null,
      _refCount: 1,
      fastWeightInitDuringBuild: true,
      activation: Swish {}
    },
    inputs: [ [SymbolicTensor] ],
    callArgs: {},
    outputTensorIndex: undefined,
    id: 548,
    originalName: 'top_activation/top_activation',
    name: 'top_activation/top_activation',
    rank: 4,
    nodeIndex: 0,
    tensorIndex: 0
  }
]
```

How can we get the outputs of a base model such that it can be input into a separate layer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, turns out, with a minimal example, it works. Simply inputting `model.outputs` into `layer.apply()` works.

```js
const tf = require(@tensorflow/tfjs)

const getModel = async function () {
    const baseModel = await tf.sequential();
    baseModel.add(tf.layers.conv2d({inputShape: [28, 28, 1], kernelSize: 5, filters: 8, strides: 1, activation: 'relu'}))
    let imgPoolLayer = tf.layers.globalAveragePooling2d({dataFormat: 'channelsLast'});
    let imgPool = imgPoolLayer.apply(baseModel.outputs);
}
getModel()
```